# bash: `read` doesn't seem to honor IFS

Tags: bash, string-parsing, ifs

I was under the impression that setting `IFS` would change the delimiter that `read` uses when separating a line of text into fields, but clearly I'm missing something:

```
# OK: 'read' sees 3 items separated by spaces
$ (IFS=' '; x="aa bb cc"; echo "'$x'"; read a b c <<< $x;\
  echo "'$a' '$b' '$c'")
'aa bb cc'
'aa' 'bb' 'cc'

# OK: 'read' sees a single item after IFS is changed
$ (IFS=','; x="aa bb cc"; echo "'$x'"; read a b c <<< $x;\
  echo "'$a' '$b' '$c'")
'aa bb cc'
'aa bb cc' '' ''

# Why doesn't 'read' see 3 items?
$ (IFS=','; x="dd,ee,ff"; echo "'$x'"; read a b c <<< $x;\
  echo "'$a' '$b' '$c'")
'dd,ee,ff'
'dd ee ff' '' ''

# OK: 'read' sees a single item when IFS is restored.
$ (IFS=' '; x="dd,ee,ff"; echo "'$x'"; read a b c <<< $x;\
  echo "'$a' '$b' '$c'")
'dd,ee,ff'
'dd,ee,ff' '' ''

# OK: 'read' again sees 3 items separated by spaces.
$ (IFS=' '; x="gg hh ii"; echo "'$x'"; read a b c <<< $x;\
  echo "'$a' '$b' '$c'")
'gg hh ii'
'gg' 'hh' 'ii'
```

Why doesn't `IFS=','` make `read` parse `dd,ee,ff` as three fields?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
# Why doesn't 'read' see 3 items?
$ (IFS=','; x="dd,ee,ff"; echo "'$x'"; read a b c <<< $x;\
  echo "'$a' '$b' '$c'")
'dd,ee,ff'
'dd ee ff' '' ''
```

Because you don't quote your variables.

```
$ ( IFS=','; x="dd,ee,ff"; echo "'$x'"; read a b c <<< "$x";\
  echo "'$a' '$b' '$c'")
'dd,ee,ff'
'dd' 'ee' 'ff'
```

EDIT: When the variable isn't quoted, the expansion causes [Word Splitting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting):

> The shell scans the results of parameter expansion, command
>   substitution, and arithmetic expansion that did not occur within
>   double quotes for word splitting.

Comment: +1 you know you have this habit of beating me in these answers :)

Comment: You should explain that `IFS` is being used when `$x` is expanded.

Comment: Thank you! I quoted my variables everywhere except where it was needed.